# Sonarcloud Cannot Analyse PR Even Though Main Branch is Analysed

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube, github-actions, sonarcloud

I have a multi-module Maven-based Java project. Experimenting on CI, I use Github Actions to automatically perform run unit tests and code quality scan on SonarCloud.

Running unit test and code quality scan to SonarCloud locally works fine. However, this error keeps popping up on Github Actions: `Project was never analyzed. A regular analysis is required before analyzing a pull request`.

I have read the documentation and several other questions, but the answer is to analyse the master branch (main branch) first, which I already did from my local, and the SonarCloud itself has been populated by code analysis from the main branch.

What should I do? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Is your project public? Sharing details would make it easier for others to understand what's happening

Comment: Yes it is public @mc1arke , what details would you require?

Comment: A link to the project in Git and in SonarQube please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, this was my bad. I had forgotten about the default value of `sonar.projectKey` value in Maven project and the incorrect key was why I could not link the repository with SonarCloud.